# Detect android device rotation

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing a game in android and I want to be able to use device rotation for moving. So, I am not sure what sensors should I use. I tried gyroscope, it will do, but there are not a lot of devices that supports gyroscope sensors. So, I want to use rotation around x,y,z axis not change like landscape/portrait mode. What sensors would be the best? I already tried to google it but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [rotation vector sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate). This combines the gyroscope, compass and acceleration sensors and outputs a vector pointing in the same direction as the phone.